# Added anaconda2 lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, results in "no version information available" warning

Tags: libraries, bashrc, datascience-anaconda

To compile a program (Caffe) I added my anaconda2 libraries to .bashrc as follows:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/
```

However, now when I run `ls` or `find` I get the following printed:

```
/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/liblzma.so.5: no version information available (required by /lib64/libselinux.so.1)
```

Or when I do Caffe related things, I get:

```
/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/liblzma.so.5: no version information available (required by /home/apples/opt/lib/libtiff.so.5)    
/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/liblzma.so.5: no version information available (required by /home/apples/opt/lib/libavcodec.so.57)
```

How can I fix this?